# Disable verbose output on build

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

When I use ST build system, "built-in output pane" prints various things like expected build output, but also `cmd` executed, active `dir` and `path` variable. Now `cmd` and `dir` are just fine, but printing `path` variable is totally unnecessary for me and it distracts actual output content, as it's just very long string of paths, shadowing all other output.

How can I instruct ST not to print `path` variable on build?

Comment: This is just in ST3 and not ST2 isn't it?  And it only happens on build failure in my observation.   That said, it is distracting I agree.

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

By adding `"quiet": true` to the Build System configuration file (JSON), you can prevent all "debug text" from appearing on build failure. This will include:

- `shell_cmd`
- `cmd`
- `dir`
- `path`

---

To exclude only `path`, you would need to modify the `Packages/Default/exec.py` file. Under the `ExecCommand` class, `run` method, look for `self.debug_text += "[path: "` and comment the line out.

To get to this file in ST3, you can use [Package​Resource​Viewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer), and type `PRV:` in the Command Palette to find `Package​Resource​Viewer: Open Resource`.

However, note that doing this, will create a file that will override the one that ships with ST3. So it is recommended to delete your override (`Preferences -> Browse Packages` from the menu, `Default` folder, `exec.py`) when a new build of ST comes out, as the official version may change to fix bugs etc. You can then re-apply your changes following the same steps as above, if it is still necessary. (Maybe an option will be added to exclude the path from the output, sometime in the future.)